# How can I process/read checkmarks on a paper form?

Tags: terminal, command-line, ocr, image-processing

I would like to process a large number of scanned paper forms (GUI or command line). I am only interested in reading (custom) checkboxes. The form looks like this:

- every line has 6 circle-shaped boxes (one is marked)
- form has has 45+ lines

After processing, I would like to have the checked value (1 … 6) of every line. I assume as there is no Optical **Character** Recognition involved (but [OMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Mark_Recognition)), this should be somewhat easier.

**Is there a way to do this from the GUI or the command line? What would be the best approach?**

**UPDATED**: scans come in PDF or JPEG (my choice). [Sample scan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcydset2salrqum/questionnaire.jpg) (380kb JPEG).

Here is an anonymized version of the form:

[image: paper form to be processed]

Comment: Do you have any solution at all for this problem currently (besides checking visually)?

Comment: No, I don't have a solution right now.

Comment: So maybe restricting it to the command line might prevent solutions which have a GUI and can still be automated from within the application. Do you want to broaden the scope a bit to look for any application solving the problem?

Comment: @patrix Done!!!

Comment: What format are the scanned documents?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample (anonymized) document? It may be easier to try certain things with available software.

Comment: Can you provide a filled document instead of an empty one? (...and if you can choose the format, use a lossless format like png and not something like jpg)

Comment: I seriously suggest looking at http://sdaps.org/SDAPS as suggested by @Deesbek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid OCR, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (a CLI image-manipulation super toolset). But you need to be shure all pages are aligned exactly the same.
I hacked together this workflow, you need to alter it for your needs and create some loops, but it can help you in the right direction.

**Make shure the position of each round is the same on each sheet**

**Extract each round and save it with the row_circle-nr** (like 04_1.png, 04_2.png, etc)

```
x=$position_of_circle_on_x
y=$position_of_circle_on_y
w=$width_of_circle_area
h=$hight_of_circle_area
input=$input_image
output=$output_row_cirleNr
convert +repage $input -crop $wx$h+$x+$y $output
```

**Calculate the area of red using histograms**
(*I prefer red, but you can also do this for blacks*)

```
RGBO=$( convert $FILE -colorspace HSL -verbose info: | grep mean | awk '{print $2}' )
REDVALUE=$( echo $RGBO | awk '{print $1}'  | cut -d. -f1 )
```

**The largest `REDVALUE` wins for each row**

Well, this is about it.

**How to install imagemagick?**

The use and installation of ImageMagick can intimidating, but this image manipulation package is the most powerfull I have encountered so far. As the installation from source can be a hassle for native OS X users I advise you to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

To install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) run this oneliner in your terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Homebrew is now installed, it is wise to follow the installer's suggestions after installation. Now we install ImageMagick using `brew`.

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Now we can use imagemagick and its `convert` tool as in the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

I am an open source enthusiast so had a look at ImageMagic to see if it is open source, it is, however the project is based in the US.  I want to see if I can help you with a German university open source project base called SDAPS.

SDAPS is specifically an OMR program.

http://sdaps.org/SDAPS

I've downloaded your test page and will try to use it to provide an answer to your question using SDAPS.

Comment: This project looks promising, I am looking forward to your answer...

Comment: Don't think I will finish my answer before the bounty expires but there you go, work comes first.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer. But this piece of software might do a better job than my hack.